# Unresolved dependencies de.joergviola#play-pdf_2.10;0.6-SNAPSHOT with Play 2.0 PDF module

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, playframework-2.2

I would like to use that module:
[Play 2.0 PDF](https://github.com/poornerd/play2pdf)
with my play 2.2.1 application, but unfortunatelly I've got an error:

```
unresolved dependencies de.joergviola#play-pdf_2.10;0.6-SNAPSHOT: not found
```

please help, or advice any other pdf library to use.
I would like to generate pdf from html and also from data/code

Comment: This [library](https://github.com/joergviola/play20-pdf) is no longer supported. We've also hit this issue and would like to know of good alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [forked repo](https://github.com/alias1/play2pdf) that has the following information:

"Currently, the module is hosted at http://alias1.github.io/play2pdf/snapshots/ Therefore, including the following lines in your Build.scala will resolve it:"

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  ...
      "de.joergviola" %% "play2pdf_2.10" % "0.6.3-SNAPSHOT"
)
val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings(
  ...
  resolvers += Resolver.url("play2pdf Repository", url("http://alias1.github.io/play2pdf/snapshots/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
)
```

This may work as a temporary work around for you until you can find a better supported PDF library for Java.

Comment: We ended up removing all references to this library from our application.

Comment: Just due to its unsupported nature and because it wasn't a key feature that we had to keep.